# Why is my Python returning a random invalid syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, syntax-error

[Error in Cmd Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyIth.png)

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Training.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Why is there a random invalid syntax error at async that prevents my code from running?

Edit: Training.py Code:
https://pastebin.com/6uwgNuG3

Comment: put your Training.py code

Comment: Added Training.py Code

Comment: @Lord the link to your Training.py Code is not accessible, fix the link

Comment: It looks like there is a function parameter called `async`. That is no longer allowed, because `async` is now a keyword. Possibly the library was written for an older version of Python. Perhaps you can get an updated version of the library.

Comment: @khelwood An updated version of tensorflow, correct?

Comment: @Lord Looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to @khelwood comment, the word 'async' is one of the reserved words.go to your .py document and change all of 'async' to something else.